# Mongodb Update: I want to $inc {field: -1} but the result is {field: -2} (ie. decrementing 1 is resulting in decrementing 2)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, decrement

I'm trying to update multiple documents with a loop, and decrement the "weeks" field in each Phase by one (1). Seems simple enough, and here is the code:

```
//Go through masterPhaseArray and decrement a week for each phase
for(let i=0; i<res.locals.masterPhaseArray.length; i++){
    
    console.log("doubles? "+res.locals.masterPhaseArray[i]._id)
    
    await Phases.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: res.locals.masterPhaseArray[i]._id}, {$inc: {weeks: -1}}, (err, doc) => {
         console.log("finished")
    })
}
```

The issue is, **it is actually decrementing by 2.**

When I tried reversing it to increment +1, **it started incrementing +2.**

I assumed I must be double-looping somehow, so I added a console.log, and here is the result:

```
[0] Connection established to mongodb://localhost:12345/teamy
[0] doubles? 5e44cc20c74f8a444851d2c3
[0] finished
```

As you can see the _id only passed once, and yet the result in the database shows:

```
Before  { weeks: 6 }
After   { weeks: 4 }
```

I've revisited the MongoDB docs for $inc, and it is very straight forward. I've googled this issue and also can't find anything like this. Appreciate any new perspectives.

Comment: After I posted this, I tried removing the "async" and "await", and it fixed the issue. But I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Check `masterPhaseArray` objects (count and order) in cycle.
It seems like somehow you add duplicate to your array in time when `Phases.findByIdAndUpdate` executed.

Cleaning from async block process and your changes of `Array` executed after cycle is done.

Comment: I tested this multiple ways, and the Array only contains (1) object. But it seems like the async/await is somehow "holding" the query, and allowing double increments?

Comment: @IsraelPeck async-await wait until your request is done.

Hmmm...
Try to create copy of your array and use 'for of'.

`const array = [ ...res.locals.masterPhaseArray ];
for(const item of array){
...your logic
}`